Text above bonding and bond angle
Taking this pictures as example, how can I display r_1, r_2 and theta_1 in my 'ABC' molecule in a similar way?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setchemfig{atom sep=4em}
    \chemfig{A-[:30]B-[:-30]C}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}



Can you please add the missing lines for a successful compile? Thank you

Sorry. Just did it.

The information you want is in section 12.6 "Add text above bonds and arc to angles" of the Chemfig manual version 1.66 of December 28, 2023

Well, thank you!

A simple solution
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \setchemfig{atom sep=4em}
        \chemfig{@{a}A-[:30]@{b}B-[:-30]@{c}C}
        \chemmove{
            \path (b) -- node[shift={(120:6pt)}] {$r_1$} (a);
            \path (b) -- node[shift={(60:6pt)}] {$r_2$} (c);
            \draw[-,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt] (b) ++(210:1.5em)
                arc[start angle=210, delta angle=120, radius=1.5em]
                node[midway,below] {$\theta_1$};
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


